# How to add metrics like 'criteria' in New Google Ad API

Tags: google-ads-api

Since Google is going to have a new API after April, some of existing reports/metrics will be unavailable such as

1. Missing the whole CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
2. Missing CriteriaId in CLICK_PERFORMANCE_REPORT

However, some of the metrics are quite import for existing reports...
May I ask if there is any way to get the old metrics in the new Google API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the mappings from the old to new api here : https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/migration/mapping

Comment: That's quite helpful. Thanks very much!

Comment: No worries. If there's a specific report you need, let me know. Otherwise, can you accept this answer?

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks a lot for your reply - I have looked through the mapping website and seems there are some columns that have been deprecated such as CriteriaId ... 
but this filed is a very important column in the report of my company... Do you have any suggestions that how can we replace it with any other fields, please?

Comment: The new ads api, you query what you want directly. What exactly are you looking for? If you give me an example of the dimensions and metrics you're looking for, I can show you a sample.

Comment: Hi dave, sorry for the late reply... here goes the query we used before and now we need to find another column from new API to replace 'google_ppc_criteria_performance.criteria' in old API ... But since I am not sure about what is the criteria about so not confused about how to do it now..

Comment: SELECT
 a.campaign_name,
 b.criteria
from
 google_ppc_criteria_performance a
left join  google_ppc_click_performance b
 on a.campaign_id = b.campaign_id
 and a.ad_group_id = b.ad_group_id
 and a.tx_date = b.tx_date
 and a.id = b.criteria_id
 and a.device = b.device

Comment: Hi Mel.
Why are you trying to join in the GAQL? 

You're making this way more complicated than it needs to be :) 

Stop and have a think. In plain English, what metrics are you looking to get back? Visualize a spreadsheet with what you need already populated. What does it look like? What are the headers?